# Batch file to rename and reverse files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder that contains `.jpg` images files named with numbers:

> ```
> 1.jpg
> 2.jpg
> ...
> 100.jpg
> ```

How can I reverse the files name so that the last one is the first one, i.e:
`100.jpg` becomes `1.jpg` and so on?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::get files count
set count=0
for %%x in (*.jpg) do (
 set /a count+=1
)

::rename
for /L %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
 set /a new=101-%%a
 ren "!new!.jpg" "temp.jpg"
 ren "%%a.jpg" "!new!.jpg"
 ren "temp.jpg" "%%a.jpg"
)
endlocal
```

I tried changing the 101 to %count% + 1
This code don't execute if the total files number are more than 50.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your approach of adapting Magoo's algorythm requires the for loop only iterating half of the count.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%a in (1,1,50) do (
 set /a new=101-%%a
 ren "!new!.jpg" "temp.jpg"
 ren "%%a.jpg" "!new!.jpg"
 ren "temp.jpg" "%%a.jpg"
)
```

where "temp.jpg" can be any filename that does not already exist.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, however it is starts from 100 and not with the biggest number.

Comment: @Amr and your sample says what?

Comment: The point is that `1.jpg` becomes `100.jpg` and `100.jpg` becomes `1.jpg`. If you want it to start at 1, then switch '%%a` and `!new!` in the three `ren` commands.

Comment: I have 100 .jpg files; this code executes only if the total files number  >= 50.
I can't understand the reason!

Comment: `%%a` is varied between 1 and 50. `new` is assigned values `101-%%a`, so (101-1)..(101-50) = 100..51. Hence the names of 1 and 100 are swapped, 2 and 99, 3 and 98 .. 50 and 51. Result is a reversal of the order of the filenames as described.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to sort all numbered jpg's not only from 1..100.
Sorting (reverse) numbers requires bringing them to a unique length.

This batch does this by adding 100 thousand to the number
(you may increase this but have to account for in the number of [0-9] in the second loops findstr)

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Base="X:\path\to\pic\folder"
Set Ext=jpg
Pushd %Base%

Set Cnt=100000
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B /A-D *.%Ext% ^|findstr /i "^[0-9]*\.%Ext%$" '
) Do Set /A "FileNo=Cnt+%%~nA" & Ren "%%A" "!FileNo!.%Ext%"
Set Cnt=0
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B *.%Ext% ^|findstr /i "^1[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.%Ext%$" ^|Sort /R '
) Do Set /A "Cnt+=1" & Ren "%%A" "!Cnt!.%Ext%"
```

Since the same names are (re-)used a powershell script will also have an intermediate step. here an additional temporary extension .tmp :

```
$Cnt=0
gci *.jpg -file|
  sort -Property @{expression={[int]$_.BaseName};Ascending = $False}|
    ForEach { $cnt++ ; Ren $_ -newname $("$Cnt.jpg.tmp" ) }
gci *.jpg.tmp -file | ForEach{ren $_ -newname $_.Basename}
```

Comment: Works fines, thank you; I updated it to use the current working directory, 

Set Base=%CD%

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the numbering is contiguous from 1 to maximum, and there are no pre-existing files named *.jpg.temp:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%N in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg^|find /c /v ""') do set max=%%N
set N=1
for /l %%N in (1 1 %max%) do (
  ren %%N.jpg !N!.jpg.temp
  set /a N+=1
)
ren *.jpg.temp *.
```

If there may be gaps in the numbering, but you want the final result to be contiguous, then you need to sort numerically as LotPings describes. I would use [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5595) - a hybrid batch/JScript sorting utility that has the ability to sort embedded numbers numerically.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set N=1
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg^|jsort /n /r') do (
  ren "%%F" !N!.jpg.temp
  set /a N+=1
)
ren *.jpg.temp *.
```